# Error in extending CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am trying to extend the CodeIgniter controller. I have created `MY_Controller.php` file, the content of the file is as following:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{ 
    function generate_key()
    {
        $n = rand(10e16, 10e20);
        return base_convert($n, 10, 36);
    }
```

Now I create my controllers by extending `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`. Following is an example of a controller:

```
class Member extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('welcome');
    }
```

I have placed the `MY_Controller.php` file in the `Application/libraries/` folder. But when I load the application, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in path\to\application\controllers\member.php
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0.2

Comment: Which version of CI are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `MY_Controller.php` in `application/core`. I tried what you have setup and got the same problem. Moving the custom controller to `core` solved the problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I had been this issue:

```
`Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found ...`
```

publishing to my remote Linux server (DreamHost) but not on locally on Windows. The issue was Linux being case sensitive: I had MY_Controller.php with a lowecase c and it wasn't autoloading.

Just in case anyone else has the same issue :)

Comment: I had this aswell, worked locally on Mac but failed when deployed to linux server.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem like this,After some search I found error was made myself,Because my controller class name was MY_Controller but file name was My_Controller[Case not matching]. Note:- In localhost I didnt have any error.

In extended controller I Use

```
class Home  extends MY_Controller{
 function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
 }
}
```

even I got the error.

After changing my file name to MY_Controller it started to work well.

MY_contrller places in application/core folder.

Comment: for those having issues with this but who are following the correct directory listings/practices ^THIS is the answer. check those cases!!